# dynamic color change using javascript

Tags: javascript

can anyone pls give sugessions or ideas on how to write the script for selecting a color in a live page so that the selected color should apply to whole page.thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Patel!

Comment: thank u jonathan sampson... im new to this jQuery.. pls help me out if i ve any doubts... thanks in adavnce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically as darren says you should change your `body` color with jQuery selector. A simple UI can be found here, for example [jQuery ColorPicker](http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/).

Answer (score 0):

A common way to do this is with a Javascript support framework like jquery.  Using jQuery you can select elements in your html and change their attributes.  For example if you wanted to set the background color for all your div elements, you would do:

```
$("div").css("background-color", "blue");
```

Here the $ function lets you select DOM elements (html elements that are part of your loaded page), and the css function applies some css rule to them.

Answer (score 0):

Online demo: http://jsbin.com/ezeze

```
document.getElementById("colors").onchange = function(){ 
  document.getElementById("container").style.color = this.value; 
}
```

--

```
<select name='colors' id='colors'> 
  <option>red</option> 
  <option>green</option> 
  <option>blue</option> 
</select> 
<div id="container"> 
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p> 
  <p>Curabitur dolor metus, aliquam in convallis ut, pharetra ac enim.</p> 
  <p>Ut lobortis justo in dolor rutrum vulputate.</p> 
</div>
```